# elasticsearch regroups aggs by regex

Tags: elasticsearch

i would like to regroup aggs by regex to get only results who start with me same prefix like

For example, suppose I have three documents as below:

```
{
    ...
    paths : [c:/]
    ...
}


{
    ...
    dimensions : [d:/]
    ...
}


{
    ...
    dimensions : [c:/new_folder]
    ...
}
```

i would like to get aggs by the HDD like

```
 "buckets" : [ {
    "key" : "c:",
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, {
    "key" : "d:",
    "doc_count" : 1
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom analyzer for those field with Keyword Tokenizer and Length Token Filter.
Or Keyword Tokenizer + Pattern Replace Char Filter if you need more complicated logic.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone, it would be a good idea to show a concrete example of how that can be achieved.

Comment: have you an example please ?

Comment: An others solution exist ? if i haven't acces to elasticsearch config ?

Comment: So, if you haven't acces to elasticsearch config, you can use scripted metric aggregation. But it will work not fast.